# Caesar Cipher Python numbers and characters

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I am new to Python and I'm trying to create a Caesar Cipher. So far, I've been using my own knowledge of Python and some online resources and I have managed to come up with the code below.

I wanted the program to be able to take both number and text values and shift them by 13 and 5. Initially, when testing for text values the program seemed to work but after adding the code to include numbers it stopped working.

Now, it does not output anything.

I have included the code and I am using IDLE 3.6
    key = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

```
def encrypt(n, plaintext):
    """Encrypt the string and return the ciphertext"""
    result = ''

    for l in plaintext.lower():
        try:
            i = (key.index(l) + n) % 26
           result += key[i]
       except ValueError:
            result += l

    return result.lower()


def decrypt(n, ciphertext):
    """Decrypt the string and return the plaintext"""
       result = ''

    for l in ciphertext:
        try:
            i = (key.index(l) - n) % 26
            result += key[i]
         except ValueError:
           result += l

   return result


def show_result(plaintext, n):
     """Generate a resulting cipher with elements shown"""
       encrypted = encrypt(n, plaintext)
    decrypted = decrypt(n, encrypted)

    print 'Rotation: %s' % n
    print 'Plaintext: %s' % plaintext
     print 'Encrytped: %s' % encrypted
     print 'Decrytped: %s' % decrypted
```

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Python

Comment: You check symbols wrong, Change `l == key1` -> `l in key1`, the first one just comparing two strings

Comment: I am able to get an output but there are no spaces for example if I input Hello 1 it outputs hello1

Comment: If you want to delete it, click on the delete button. Don't vandalize the post.

Comment: Are the bodies of the encrypt and decrypt functions properly indented in your code? Because they aren't in this post!

Comment: Have you found any solution?